python-mbedtls TLS Server and Client using certificates
I am trying to set up a simple client and server using python-mbedtls, where only the server shall be certificated via one intermediate certificate. I was able to make it work without an intermediate certificate but I do not get why it is not working with it.
I have the following server.py and client.py but unfortunately I always get this error:
mbedtls.exceptions.TLSError: TLSError([0x2700] 'X509 - Certificate verification failed, e.g. CRL, CA or signature check failed')

Does anyone have an idea what could be the problem?
client.py:
hostname = "www.example.com"
port = 60187

# this is where the Client class provided by python-mbedtls is inserted

def main() -> None:
    root_crt = x509.CRT.from_file("root.crt")
    inter_crt = x509.CRT.from_file("inter.crt")

    trust_store = TrustStore()
    trust_store.add(root_crt)
    trust_store.add(inter_crt)

    conf = TLSConfiguration(
        trust_store=trust_store,
        validate_certificates=True,
    )

    message = "Hello world!"

    with Client(
        conf, socket.SOCK_STREAM, ("127.0.0.1", port), hostname
    ) as cli:
        _enable_debug_output(cli.context)
        _set_debug_level(2)
        cli.do_handshake()
        received = cli.echo(message.encode("utf-8"), 1024)
    print(received.decode("utf-8"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

server.py:
hostname = "www.example.com"
port = 60187

# this is where the Server class of the server.py provided by python-mbedtls is inserted

# from the unit tests of python-mbedtls:
def make_root_ca(
    # pylint: disable=too-many-arguments
    subject: Optional[str] = None,
    not_before: Optional[dt.datetime] = None,
    not_after: Optional[dt.datetime] = None,
    serial_number: Optional[int] = None,
    basic_constraints: Optional[BasicConstraints] = None,
    digestmod: Optional[hashlib.Algorithm] = None,
) -> Tuple[CRT, _Key]:
    if subject is None:
        subject = "OU=test, CN=Trusted CA"
    if not_before is None:
        not_before = dt.datetime.utcnow()
    if not_after is None:
        not_after = not_before + dt.timedelta(days=90)
    if serial_number is None:
        serial_number = 0x123456
    if basic_constraints is None:
        basic_constraints = BasicConstraints(True, -1)
    if digestmod is None:
        digestmod = hashlib.sha256
    key = RSA()
    key.generate()
    crt = CRT.selfsign(
        csr=CSR.new(key, subject, digestmod()),
        issuer_key=key,
        not_before=not_before,
        not_after=not_after,
        serial_number=serial_number,
        basic_constraints=basic_constraints,
    )
    return crt, key

# from the unit tests of python-mbedtls:
def make_crt(
    # pylint: disable=too-many-arguments
    issuer_crt: CRT,
    issuer_key: str,
    subject: Optional[str] = None,
    not_before: Optional[dt.datetime] = None,
    not_after: Optional[dt.datetime] = None,
    serial_number: Optional[int] = None,
    basic_constraints: Optional[BasicConstraints] = None,
    digestmod: Optional[hashlib.Algorithm] = None,
) -> Tuple[CRT, str]:
    if subject is None:
        subject = "OU=test, CN=hostname"
    if not_before is None:
        not_before = issuer_crt.not_before
    if not_after is None:
        not_after = issuer_crt.not_after
    if serial_number is None:
        serial_number = 0x123456
    if basic_constraints is None:
        basic_constraints = BasicConstraints()
    if digestmod is None:
        # TODO: issuer_crt.digestmod should work but doesn't.
        digestmod = hashlib.sha256
    key = RSA()
    key.generate()
    crt = issuer_crt.sign(
        csr=CSR.new(key, subject, digestmod()),
        issuer_key=issuer_key,
        not_before=not_before,
        not_after=not_after,
        serial_number=serial_number,
        basic_constraints=basic_constraints,
    )
    return crt, key

# custom function to create my certificates:
def create_and_export_certificates():
    root_crt, root_key = make_root_ca()
    inter_crt, inter_key = make_crt(
        root_crt, root_key, subject="OU=test, CN=Intermediate CA"
    )
    ee_crt, ee_key = make_crt(
        inter_crt, inter_key, subject=f"OU=test, CN={hostname}"
    )
    with open("root.crt", "wt") as file:
        file.write(root_crt.to_PEM())
    with open("inter.crt", "wt") as file:
        file.write(inter_crt.to_PEM())

    print(root_crt.verify(inter_crt))
    print(inter_crt.verify(ee_crt))

    return (ee_crt, inter_crt, root_crt), ee_key


def main() -> NoReturn:
    (ee_crt, inter_crt, root_crt), ee_key  = create_and_export_certificates()

    conf = TLSConfiguration(
        certificate_chain=([ee_crt, inter_crt, root_crt], ee_key),
        validate_certificates=False
    )

    with Server(conf, socket.SOCK_STREAM, ("127.0.0.1", 60_111)) as srv:
        _enable_debug_output(srv.context)
        _set_debug_level(2)
        srv.run(partial(echo_handler, packet_size=4069))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import faulthandler

    faulthandler.enable()
    with suppress(KeyboardInterrupt):
        main()


What I tried so far:

tried looking into the test cases of the repository

What I expected:

was expecting to establish an encrypted communication between client and server


This is a huge amount of undocumented code, please reduce to the bare minimum needed to show the problem. Because you've tried to put everything into the code it makes it really hard to find out where the problem might be. But one obvious thing is that the intermediate CA you've created does not seem to have basic constrains CA:true.

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.

@SteffenUllrich That fixed it, thank you so much! I tried to reduce my example code to the main parts, I am quite new here, so thank you for the patience :)
